# Dynamic typing of a typescript function, based on the the definition of sibiling properties

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm trying out Zod, and I wanted to use it to provide dynamic compile time type information to functions I'm defining, within a simple object. The object looks like this:

```ts
import { z } from "zod";

export const Component = {
  inputs: {
    numbers: {
      doc: "The numbers to sum",
      type: z.array(z.number()),
    },
  },
  outputs: {
    sum: {
      doc: "The sum of the numbers",
      type: z.number(),
    },
  }
};
```

I then find myself needing to define these types to create the dynamic properties I want:

```ts
export type InputValues = ParameterSetValues<typeof Component.inputs>;
export type OutputValues = ParameterSetValues<typeof Component.outputs>;
```

Lastly, my simple function works and the types are validated as I expect!, like so:

```ts
export function sum({ numbers }: InputValues): OutputValues {
  const sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  return { sum };
}
```

OK this all works fine and good. Here's the types I've defined (in a separate file) to make this work.

```ts
import type { z } from "zod";

export type ParameterDefinition = {
  doc?: string;
  label?: string;
  type: z.ZodType<any, any, any>;
};

export type ParameterSet = {
  [key: string]: ParameterDefinition;
};

export type ParameterSetValues<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends ParameterDefinition
    ? z.infer<T[key]["type"]>
    : never;
};

export type ActionDefinition = {
  doc?: string;
  label?: string;
};

export type ActionSet = {
  [key: string]: ActionDefinition;
};

export interface ComponentDefinition {
  inputs: ParameterSet;
  outputs: ParameterSet;
  actions: ActionSet;
}
```

So, here's where things fall apart for me: **If I specify the `ComponentDefinition` type on my component variable (so I can start referring to these functions by type), I cannot figure out how to refer to this function with dynamic types!**

I'd like the component to look like this:

```ts
import { z } from "zod";
import { ComponentDefinition} from "somewhere";

export const Component: ComponentDefinition = {
  inputs: {
    numbers: {
      doc: "The numbers to sum",
      type: z.array(z.number()),
    },
  },
  outputs: {
    sum: {
      doc: "The sum of the numbers",
      type: z.number(),
    },
  },
  actions: {
    doSum: {
      doc: "some documentation string":
      call: sum,
    }
  }
};
```

Where the `call` property is a reference to the function I defined using the dynamic types, but as soon as I add that `ComponentDefinition` type to the `Component` object, the dynamic types fail to work properly.

What am I missing here? Is there a workable solution? What would the type signature of the `call` property need to be? Bonus points if I can get rid of the boilerplate `InputValues` and `OutputValues` types somehow.

Thanks!

EDIT: It seems like simply typing the object makes things fail, this doesn't work as expected:

```ts
export const Inputs: { [key: string]: ParameterDefinition } = {
  numbers: {
    doc: "The numbers to sum",
    type: z.array(z.number()),
  },
};

export type ParameterValues<T extends { [key: string]: ParameterDefinition }> =
  {
    [key in keyof T]: z.infer<T[key]["type"]>;
  };

export type InputValues = ParameterValues<typeof Inputs>;
// InputValues = { [x: string]: any } at this point.

If I remove the type declaration from `Inputs` it works as expected, however. Confusing! It's as if `typeof` is disregarding the actual concrete members of `Inputs`.
```